# Magento Product data in Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product') not clearing?

Tags: php, magento

Magento Product data in Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product') not clearing if product id not available in database

Eg:

Product ID - 586  (Poduct present)

Product ID - 999  (Product not present in Magento)

**Not Working:**

```
    $productModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
    $_product=$productModel->load('586');
    echo $_product->getId()."<br>";

    $productModels = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
    $_products=$productModels->load('999');
    echo $_products->getId()."<br>";
```

> **Output:**
>
> 586
>
> 586

**Working:**

```
    $productModel = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
    $_product=$productModel->load('999');
    echo $_product->getId()."<br>";

    $productModels = Mage::getSingleton('catalog/product');
    $_products=$productModels->load('586');
    echo $_products->getId()."<br>";
```

> **Output:**
>
> 586

Anyone please help!..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use  Mage::getModel() instead of Mage::getSingleton().

```
<?php
$productModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_product=$productModel->load('586');
echo $_product->getId()."<br>";

$productModels = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
$_products=$productModels->load('999');
echo $_products->getId()."<br>";
?>

Output 
586
```

Model create new instance when Singleton use original instance.

Comment: Get Model creates new Product object. I am not sure if this is the best way to get product information.

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the instance in between.

```
$_product->clearInstance();
```